# Should I Use Core Data With A REST API Backend?

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking

I am a little confused on what core data is exactly used for. I have googled a lot on it, and a lot of posts on core data are about using Core Data for local storage. At the moment I am developing an app with a REST API backend, and I use `AFNetworking` to send/receive responses to the REST API.

What I am wondering is if I should instead use Core Data to communicate with the REST API? Is Core Data able to do such a thing? Would it be best to use Core Data or to use `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, core data is not used to communicate with a back-end (or anything else). As you said, it is for local storage. That's it.

To communicate with a web service or other Internet API, use one of various tools for the job such as `NSURLConnection` or AFNetworking.

Comment: Use `NSURLSession`, `NSURLConnection` is outdated

Comment: This a common misconception about Core Data. It is *not* just for local storage. There are at least 20 other benefits of using Core Data. It is primarily an object model layer used to maintain object graphs that are always in a state of integrity.

Comment: @Scenario But the question is asking about using CoreData to communicate with a rest API. In that context, CoreData is not what is needed. This question is not about all of the other benefits of CoreData. Please explain how my answer is not correct in the scope of the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need CoreData's possibilities of course you should not use it. But if you would like to have some data locally try CoreData or [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/).

From [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/) wiki:

> Until now we have focused on transient objects within RestKit. For
>   many applications transient objects are completely the right choice --
>   if your data set is constantly changing and your use-cases can rely on
>   the availability of network access, using transient objects is a
>   simpler, easier way forward. But for some applications, you really
>   need the full power of a queryable, persistent object model for
>   performance, flexibility, offline access, etc. Apple has provided a
>   great solution in Core Data. RestKit integrates with Core Data to
>   bridge the gap between your remote server backend and your local
>   object model.