# Core data with REST api

Tags: ios, rest, core-data

I'd really like some advice on how to approach this paradigm. I have a REST server with several endpoints which I would like to query with an IOS app. The problem i'm having is that some tutorials/sites recommend [integrating core data](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/restkit-tutorial-how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-into-core-data-9326af750e10), by feeding the JSON into core data and then rendering Views with ManagedObjects etc. while other's [dont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403893/should-i-use-core-data-with-a-rest-api-backend).

[image: data flow for app]

However I have a mainly read only application, which needs to display information stored at web server URL's. Are there major pro's/con's in using core data for my use case?

Thanks for reading and please feel free to link articles/posts as appose to writing answers!

Comment: Pro of CoreData is the caching ability. Meaning when the user reopens your application after fully terminating the application, the user can see previous information while new information is being loaded (Would need something in the UI to display new information is on the way however so the user does not think the application is stuck).